# How to add views to a blueprint in separate files

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

I have a huge application that was getting hard to update its views. To 'fix' this, I had separate the views into a few files, using [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/). The problem is that the blueprints are also getting very big, because the long documentation that each view has and the different verifications that each view requires.

I had tried to do an `import` like this:

[image: Import]

Where I have a main file that contains the Flask application (which imports the blueprint), a file that contains the blueprint and a file the imports the blueprint and configure the views in it. The problem is that with this approach the views are not rendered, because flow reasons.

The main file, in the root of a folder:

```py
from flask import Flask

from source import test

application = Flask(__name__)

application.register_blueprint(test)

application.run()
```

The blueprint file, inside a subfolder in the root folder:

```py
from flask import Blueprint

test = Blueprint('test', __name__)
```

The view file, inside the same subfolder as the blueprint file:

```py
from .test import test

@test.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return 'home'
```

I had also tried to add the blueprint decorator to a declared function, this way the views are add to the blueprint in the blueprint file, but I don't think this is a good approach or a scalable approach - and it didn't work ^ - ^.

I expect to create a blueprint in a file, import the blueprint in other files and add views to the blueprint and then import the blueprint and add it to the Flask application.

Comment: Can you share the folder structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In root folder change main file:

```
from flask import Flask

from source.listener import test

application = Flask(__name__)

application.register_blueprint(test)

application.run()
```

The blueprint file, inside a subfolder in the root folder:

listener.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

from source.view import home


test = Blueprint('test', __name__)

test.add_url_rule('/home', view_func=home,methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

The view file, inside the same subfolder as the blueprint file:

```
from flask import request

def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['name']
        return "Welcome "+user
    else:
        return 'home'
```

Get Request O/P:

```
 Home
```

Post Request O/P:

```
Welcome username
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to import the `views` content in `blueprint` file.

I have created the scenario and able to get the `view`. Additionally, I have updated the naming convention.

Folder structure:

```
.
├── app.py
└── blueprints
    ├── example_blueprint.py
    ├── example_views.py
    └── __init__.py
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from blueprints.example_blueprint import bp

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(bp)
```

`blueprints/example_blueprint.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('bp', __name__,
                        template_folder='templates')

from .example_views import *
```

`blueprints/example_views.py`:

```
from .example_blueprint import bp

@bp.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return 'home'
```

`blueprints/__init__.py`: Blank file

Output:

[image: blueprint example]

Running the application:

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.3
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
Werkzeug==0.15.4
```

**Reference:**

- [Flask documentation on Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/#the-concept-of-blueprints)

Answer (score 1):

The view module isn't discovered since only the Blueprint object is imported.

From the organization of your Blueprint and particularly the import that you have shared in your main file, I can deduct the existence of an **__init__.py** in the blueprint folder that exports the blueprint object.

Importing the views in that file should have the app discover the views registered in the blueprint.
*i.e.*

`blueprint/__init__.py`:

```py
from .test import test
from . import views
```